# Void at Purchase Order Netsuite

Tags: transactions, netsuite

I want to make a transaction with my PO, I want it to be "void" but usually "void" appears in the PO edit type. My PO doesn't have an edit button. How do I "void" this PO[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QOs1.png)

I've tried closing, the expectation becomes "void" but the PO doesn't "void"